# Is there a way to show that $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by $ without also showing that its the smallest positive linear combination?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, gcd-and-lcm

Is there a way to show that $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$ without also showing that it is the smallest positive linear combination? i.e. Can it be shown that there exists an $a$ and $b$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$? If there is such a proof, what is the proof?

I have seen lots of proofs for $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$ that also shows it is the smallest but I was wondering if there was one where it did not require that too? Maybe using factorization of integers? Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Use the Euclidean Algorithm and then work backwards to construct $x$ and $y$ explicitly, or use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. In going along that path, we do not explicitly show the gcd is the smallest positive linear combination. However, showing that there is no smaller positive linear combination is extremely easy.

Comment: There are many other ways to show that the gcd is a linear combination. For let $a=da_1$ and $b=db_1$ where $a_1$ and $b_1$ are relatively prime. We can show there exist $s$ and $t$ such that $a_1s+b_1t=1$ by showing that $a_1t\equiv 1\pmod{b_1}$ has a solution. There are many tools to do this, including a basic pigeonhole argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let's revise the definition of GCD.

*Let $a, b$ be integers with at least one of them being non-zero. A positive integer $d$ is said to be the GCD of $a$ and $b$ and denoted by $d = (a, b)$*

- *if $d \mid a, d \mid b$*
- *if there is any integer $c$ with $c \mid a, c \mid b$ then $d \mid c$*

Let $b$ be the non-zero integer out of $a$ and $b$. It is easy to show that there exist unique integers $q, r$ such that $a = bq + r$ where $0 \leq r < |b|$ and then further show that $(a, b) = (b, r)$.

This is the euclidean algorithm to find GCD of $a, b$. Applying this algorithm we get remainders $r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n}$ such that $r_{n} = 0$ and then $r_{n - 1}$ is the the GCD of $a, b$. We have the relations $$a = bq_{1} + r_{1}, b = r_{1}q_{2} + r_{2}, \cdots r_{i - 2} = r_{i - 1}q_{i} + r_{i}$$ From these relations we can get $ r_{n - 1} = ax + yb$ with $x, y$ being integers. A numerical example should help to explain this clearly.

Let $ a = 21, b = 15$. Then we have $$21 = 1\cdot 15 + 6, 15 = 2\cdot 6 + 3, 6 = 2\cdot 3 + 0$$ so that $3$ is the GCD. And doing back calculation we get $$3 = 15 - 2\cdot 6 = 15 - 2(21 - 1\cdot 15) = 3\cdot 15  + (-2)\cdot 21 = 15x + 21y$$ where $x = 3, y = -2$.

Answer (score 0):

If ax + by = M then gcd(a,b) divides both a and b so it divides M.  So if there are *any* solutions at all they must be at least as big as gcd(a,b).  The proof don't need to rely on gcd(a, b) being the smallest; just that one that small exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, this argument does not prove that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$, which is what the OP asks for. (It could be altered to do so, using some of André Nicolas's comments, for example.)

Comment: My interpretation was the OP didn't need or want a proof.  S/he wanted to know if it was a requirement of the proof that gcd(a,b) is the smallest solution.  Answer: The proofs don't require it to be the smallest but it's very clear and easy to show that is has to be the smallest hypothetical answer.  If I misunderstood the OP's question, I apologize.

Comment: @fleablood that was my mistake, sorry, I did want to see an alternative proof too, not only that it existed.